# How to combine a list and dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, arraylist, type-conversion

1) How we can combine a dict with list and return the result as JSON?
Have tried to combine list_1(dict) and list_2(list), but getting error. Also, after converting them to strings can combine but could not decode back to JSON format(as expected result below).

2) Also, how to replace a value within JSON and maintain it as JSON?

```
list_1 = [{'title': 'NEWBOOK', 'downloads': '4', 'views': '88'}]

list_2 = {'title': 'MASTERMIND', 'downloads': '16', 'views': '156'}

list_3 = {
       'a': 'b',
       'c': 'd',
       'e': [{
         'f': 'g',
         'l': 'm'
         }]
       }
```

Script which I have tried as below.

```
combine = list_1 +  list_2



for z in list_3['e']:

list_3 = list_3.replace(z, combine)

Expected_json = json.dumps(list_3)

print(list_3)
```

Error1:

```
combine = list_1 +  list_2
```

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list

Error2:

```
list_3 = list_3.replace(z, combine)
```

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Expected result:

```
list_3 = {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": [{
            "f": "g",
            "l": "m"
        },
        {
            "title": "NEWBOOK",
            "downloads": "4",
            "views": "88"
        },
        {
            "title": "MASTERMIND",
            "downloads": "16",
            "views": "156"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like `list_3['e'].extend(list_1); list_3['e'].append(list_2)`.  This data is kind of a weird mishmash though.  Where are you getting it from?  If you're generating it yourself, there's probably a way of organizing that to make these downstream applications simpler.

Comment: do you always want to add the lists in the "e" key in the dict. i mean do you know at which key entry in list_3 do you want to add the list

Comment: It's an existing application so I don't have control on it , need it badly as I am mentioned.

Comment: Yes want to replace the entire dictionary within list_3[e].

Answer (score 1):

Simply append to the list in the dictionary

```
list_3['e'].append(list_2)
list_3['e'].append(list_1[0])
print(list_3)

{
    'a':
    'b',
    'c':
    'd',
    'e': [{
        'f': 'g',
        'l': 'm'
    }, {
        'title': 'MASTERMIND',
        'downloads': '16',
        'views': '156'
    }, {
        'title': 'NEWBOOK',
        'downloads': '4',
        'views': '88'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json    
list_1 = [{'title': 'NEWBOOK', 'downloads': '4', 'views': '88'}]

list_2 = {'title': 'MASTERMIND', 'downloads': '16', 'views': '156'}

list_3 = {
       'a': 'b',
       'c': 'd',
       'e': [{
         'f': 'g',
         'l': 'm'
         }]
       }


list_3['e'].append(list_1[0])

list_3['e'].append(list_2)
json_list = json.dumps(list_3)
```

if you want to add more lists to the location you do the following

```
b= json.loads(json_list)
b['e'].append(your_new_dict)
json_list = json.dumps(b)
```

if you have no idea what list_1 and list_2 are then you can test for the class type and append them accordingly. Like

```
if(type(list_1)==list):
    list_3['e'].append(list_1[0])
if(type(list_2)==dict):
    list_3['e'].append(list_2)
```

if you dont know at which point in list_3 you want to append the list. you do something like the following. Assuming there is only one list in list_3

```
for x in list_3.values():
    if(type(x)==list):
        x.append(list_1[0])
        x.append(list_2)
```

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't stop the requirement still and need to add 'new' to list3 as below(Expected result). This is due to the complex nature of the json here from downstream application.
The challenge faced here is  unable to append or extend using python as new is not a proper list or dict. Any solution will be appreciated.

new =  'm':{'n' : 'o'}
list3 = {
    'a':
        [{'b' : 'c'},{'d' : 'e'}],
    'f':
        [{
            'g':
                {'h' : 'i'},
            'j':
                {'k' : 'l'}
        }]

}

Comment: Expected result:

{
    "a":
        [{"b" : "c"},{"d" : "e"}],
    "f":
        [{
            "g":
                {"h" : "i"},
            "j":
                {"k" : 'l"},
            "m":
                {"n" : "o"}
        }]

}

Comment: so you want to append new to list3, but the problem is that new is not a proper dict??

Comment: In order for all of the above to work, you have to make sure that "new" is a dict. you can use the python dict constructor to create dicts. Find some examples here, https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/dict.  However, if the "new" datapoint that you are getting is changing on every call, then give us some examples and we can might be able to help you more...but dict() constructor should work for you. Let me know if you need examples...

Comment: I have gone through the documentation, one thing which I need to highlight is that the new = 'm':{'n' : 'o'} structure will not change and its value is known always. Just want to append 'new' to the dict.

Comment: if its a string use eval to convert the string into dict. Prepend and append '{', and '}' respectively to "new". then type >>>new_dict=eval(new). new_dict is now a python dict type that you can append to list 3...

Comment: I have tried above but received error.
list_3 = { 'a': [{'b' : 'c'},{'d' : 'e'}], 'f': [{ 'g': {'h' : 'i'}, 'j': {'k' : 'l'} }] }

new = str({'m':{'n' : 'o'} })

print(type(list_3))

new_dict = eval(new)

print(type(new_dict))

print(list_3.append(new_dict))

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: thats because you are appending to list_3 which is a dict, you want to append to list_3['f']...

Comment: if you want to append to list_3, you just add a new key value pair. so list_3["new_key"]= new_dict